# Validate kannel configuration (aside from running kannel)

Tags: kannel

Is there a way to make sure that a certain Kannel configuration is consistent?

Probably I could write a script that checks that all parameter groups have exactly one

```
'group = '
```

all mandatory groups are present, all included files are present and valid themselves, etc.

However, maybe there's a standard way already?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any standard tool to check configuration. However looks like "https://redmine.kannel.org/projects/kannel/repository/entry/trunk/test/test_cfg.c" may be used for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In Kannel configuration file, there are many groups for different purposes.
For admin details.

```
group = core
```

for modems where you define your USB modem configurations.

```
group = modems
```

If you are looking for a complete configuration file. You can [get](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VtH8OLg9fVB7qln5oW2oRaEJ73Sfb7-94M_Ngs4UfEo/edit?usp=sharing) a complete configuration file from here.